# Prove that $\prod _{k=1}^{\infty } \prod _{n=1}^{\infty } n^{\frac{k}{n^{\text{ks}} \zeta (k s)}}=e^{-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sigma_1(m) \: P'(m \: s)}$

Tags: infinite-product

Where $ \sigma_1(m) $ and $ P'(m \: s) $ are the Divisor function and the derivative of the Prime Zeta function, respectively.

I've tried to expand the left side via the Euler Product of the Zeta function and then take the logarithmic derivative, but I get hung up on the reciprocal Zeta part.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give some more context on this problem like where you find this formula?  I don't want to invest time into trying to prove it if it turns out to be nonsense

Comment: This question was asked by a Miami recreational math society. They are no longer taking answers and I couldn't figure it out. They meet biweekly so I'll have the answer in a week.

Comment: @DecarbonatedOdes I believe the first step would be to take the logarithm.